# Google recaptcha "file_get_contents" not working.why?Is there any working alternative?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Google recaptcha to my site.In order to implement i tried this code

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
{

$recaptcha_secret = "mysitekey";
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
$response = json_decode($response, true);

if($response["success"] === true){
    echo "Form Submit Successfully.";
}else{
    echo "You are a robot";
}

}
```

But the result was

```
 504 Gateway Time-out

 The server didn't respond in time.
```

Can anyone figure out the problem.
please share working example or code if possible.Thanks.

Comment: can you asscee that uri?

Comment: Try using curl. Your hosting may block file_get_contents.